# Reproducing Kernel and the continuity of the evaluation functional $e_{t}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm working on Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces and I had a problem proving the the continuity of the evaluation functional $e_{t}$ ($e_{t}(\phi) = \phi(t)$).

> **Theorem**
>   A *Hilbert Space* of complex valued functions on E has a *reproducing kernel* then all the evaluation functionals $e_{t}$, $t \in E$, are continuous on $\mathcal{H}$.

**Proof**: If $\mathcal{H}$ has a reproducing kernel $K$ then for any $t \in E$, we have

$$\forall \phi \in \mathcal{H} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  e_{t}(\phi) = \langle \phi, K(\cdot, t) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$$

Thus the evaluation functional $e_{t}$ is linear and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

$$|e_{t}(\phi)| = |\langle\phi, K(\cdot, t) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}| \ \ \leq \ \ ||\phi|| \ \ ||K(\cdot, t)|| = ||\phi|| \ \ [K(t, t)]^{1/2}$$

$$ |e_{t}(\phi)| \leq ||\phi|| \ \ [K(t, t)]^{1/2}$$

Then $e_{t}$ is bounded then $e_{t}$ is continuous.

How can I conclude that $e_{t}$ is bounded from the last inequality? As far as I know $[K(t, t)]^{1/2}$ is not bounded.

Comment: This shows that $e_t$ is a bounded linear functional for each $t$. $t$ is fixed.

Comment: That what I was thinking. How can I ensure that $K(t, t)$ is not infinity?

Answer (score 1):

You have the assumption that
$$\forall \phi \in \mathcal{H} \quad  e_{t}(\phi) = \langle \phi, K(\cdot, t)\rangle _{\mathcal{H}}$$
Consider the meaning of the above statement.  The thing on the right implicitly says that $K(\cdot,t)$ is an element of $\mathcal H$, because otherwise the inner product is not defined. Any functional of this form is bounded. Specifically,
$$|e_{t}(\phi)| \le  \|\phi\|_{\mathcal H}\, \| K(\cdot, t)\|_{\mathcal{H}}$$

Comment: It's the reproducing property of the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space. $$\forall t \in E, \forall \phi \in \mathcal{H} \langle \phi, K(\cdot, t) \rangle = \phi(t) = e_{t}(\phi)$$

Comment: @matiskay That was a rhetorical question. I reworded the post to clarify this point.